# Pymongo Concurrency and the Multiprocessing Module

Tags: python, mongodb, multiprocessing, pymongo

I'm trying to understand the best way to parallelize the processing of queries or query results using pymongo.

All of my reading says that you should have a small number of MongoClient() objects. Say I have two different implementations of the module data_interface.py

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)

def execute_query(id_to_find):
    db = client['mydatabase']
    my_collection = db.my_collection
    data_cursor = my_collection.find({'_id':my_id_to_find})
    return data_cursor
```

and

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db = client['mydatabase']
my_collection = db.my_collection

def execute_query(id_to_find):
    data_cursor = my_collection.find({'_id':my_id_to_find})
    return data_cursor
```

Assume the function process_data does some simple calculations and the collection is many to one (one id query returns a thousand results) and suppose I have:

```
import data_interface
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process_data(ids_to_process):
    # ids_to_process is a list of ids to query
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    results = pool.map(query_and_process_data, ids_to_process)

def query_and_process_data(id_to_query):
    cursor = data_interface.execute_query(id_to_query)
    processed_results = []
    for result in cursor:
        processed_result = process_data(result)
        processed_results.append(processed_result)

    return processed_results
```

Or:

```
import data_interface
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process_data(ids_to_process):
    # ids_to_process is a list of ids to query
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    for id in ids_to_process:
        cursor = data_interface.execute_query(id)
        data_returned = cursor[:]
        results = pool.map(process_data, data_returned)
```

There are 4 different implementations here. Is there an obvious flaw in any of the implementations? In each implementation, I believe a MongoClient gets created for each process when Pool creates a new python interpreter. Does the second implementation of data_interface support parallel queries? Or do I need a new instance of the collection object to achieve that? The difference between the two implementations of process_data is whether or not parallel queries are executed or each document is processed in parallel.

Note: None of this code has been tested and there are probably mistakes in it. I hope it's clear enough to convey my ideas.

Comment: Which is most efficient? Measure them.

Comment: Measuring them would take several months of work. I will edit the question to make it clear that I'm looking for someone's intuition based on experience or something I don't understand.

Comment: No one's intuition about Python with random modules talking to a non-trivial database on an arbitrary configuration is very good. Months of work? Lookup [module timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html).

Comment: I say months of work because of the stage of development we are in, not because it's a hard thing to do.